# ASP.NET: Repeater with Button inside GridView: Call OnRowCommand of the GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a asp:Repeater in one of my asp:GridView columns. In the template of the repeater I have a button. When that button is clicked, how can I get the OnRowCommand of the GridView to be called instead of the Repeater one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a button click handler? That would allow you to avoid the GridView and Repeater command events.

Answer (score 1):

Wire the button event directly or take a look at bubbleevent